# Spread attributes for an element in Angular >=6 template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this in my code...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'generic-input',
  template: `<div><input [formControl]="control"/></div>`,
})
export class GenericInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('config') config = {placeholder: 'Testability', disabled: true, type: 'text'};

  control;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = new FormControl();
  }

}
```

I would like to spread the attributes in the config object by using some sort of a loop or something else so that the rendered html 
is as follows:

```
<div><input placeholder='Testability', disabled=true type='text' [formControl]="control"/></div>
```

**Note:**
This following is not an option:

```
   <div><input [placeholder]='config.placeholder', [disabled]='config.disabled' [formControl]="control"/></div>
```

Any help and ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Add a template variable:

```
<div><input #v [formControl]="control"/></div>
```

2.Bind `ViewChild` in ts:

```
@ViewChild('v')
v: ElementRef
```

3.Fill values in its `nativeElement` property:

```
const el = this.v.nativeElement
Object.keys(this.config).forEach(key => el[key] = this.config[key])
```

**Update**

Complete component.ts file would look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div><input #v></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('v')
  v: ElementRef;

  config = { placeholder: 'Testability', disabled: true, type: 'text' };

  ngOnInit() {
    const el = this.v.nativeElement;
    Object.keys(this.config).forEach(key => el[key] = this.config[key]);
  }
}
```