# Pass props using ES6 spread operator

Tags: angular, typescript

`ChildComponent.ts`

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name?: string;
  @Input() email?: string;
  // A lot more props

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

`ParentComponent.ts`

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childProps = {
    name: "johnny",
    email: "johnny@gmail.com"
  };

  constructor() {}    
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

`ParentComponent.html`

This works:

```
<app-child [name]="childProps.name" [email]="childProps.email"></app-child>
```

But how do I pass all props using ES6 spread operator?

```
<app-child [*]="{...childProps}"></app-child>
```

Comment: That is **not** supported in [Angular template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: Hmm... mostly all other web frameworks supports this

Comment: I'm not saying they don't, just that Angular doesn't. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47297089/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58116963/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53845004/3001761. Also note AngularJS is a different framework entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider defining an interface for the props and then pass as an object, no need for spread or using multiple `@Inputs()`.

```js
// child.ts

export interface ChildProps {
  name?: string,
  email?: string  ​
}

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
 ​@Input() allProps?: ChildProps;
​
 ​constructor() {}

 ​ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```js
//parent.ts

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childProps = {
    name: "johnny",
    email: "johnny@gmail.com"
  };

  constructor() {}    
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```html
<!-- parent-template.html -->

<app-child [allProps]="childProps"></app-child>
```

```html
<!-- child-template.html -->

<div>{{ allProps?.name }}</div>
```